# Sharepoint Online - List Existing “Send To Connections" in C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I need to create a C# method that Lists existing "Send To Conections" inside Shapoint Online Central Administration (https://MYSERVER-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TA_OfficialFileAdmin.aspx), returning a List with connection Display Names.

That's possible?

Example: private List GetSendToConnections(){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have CSOM/REST methid available as yet for this .

Dont have any official documentation for this, but you can check the link below where they have mentioned it.

Technet link - [Enable and Set Record Management settings using PowerShell & CSOM and Route records to Record Center Site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35809.sharepoint-online-enable-and-set-record-management-settings-using-powershell-csom-and-route-records-to-record-center-site.aspx#Manually_Configure_Send_To_Connection)